# Why isn't Red Angel simply communicating with normal language instead of giving clues?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In the recently released S02E09 of *Star Trek: Discovery*, we learned that

> the story is going The Terminator way. Basically, AI would destroy all sentient beings from the galaxy in the future. And, Red Angel is a human (which Spock confirmed) from future who wants to prevent this outcome.

Why didn't Red Angel simply tell Discovery crew or Spock using normal language?

Comment: Because of the power of the plot! Also, this question will probably be answered in the coming episodes, so it definitely falls under the future works policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recent episode S02E10 "The Red Angel" of *Star Trek: Discovery*, Burnham asked the same question.

In the episode, initially it was deduced that

> future Burnham was the Red Angel (which turned out to be wrong).

After this deduction, Burnham asked the question:

> "Let's assume for a moment I am the Red Angel. If I knew about an apocalypse, why wouldn't I say so?"

Initially, Spock joked:

> "Perhaps you simply have a penchant for the dramatic."

But, later he gave the correct answer (which he had got from the Project Daedalus file found in Airiam's memory):

> "The suit was emitting tetryonic radiation, which would limit traditional radio and sensor communication. That would explain my difficulties in mind-melding with it."

Comment: With the comment in brackets in the first spoiler tag, you're assuming that there is only one Red Angel and it's always the same individual. With 5 more episodes in this season it's all still up in the air.